# How to Fillna with mode of the same column group by another text categorical column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, fillna

I am trying to fill with mode of the same column(this is categorical text column) group by another column(this is categorical text column too).

Note that similar question posted by Krishna Bandhakavi on Sep 23 at 3:05 but didn't help in my case.

Attempt 1:

```
df['col2'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()))
    df_cpt['col2'].unique()
```

no error but gives below and observe that nan is still present.

```
array(['Passed', nan, 'Pending', 'Registered', 'Applied for sign Off',
       'Verbal', 'Not Applicable'], dtype=object)
```

Attempt 2:

```
df['col2'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().index[0))
```

gives below error:

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

```
df
--

col1   col2   col3   col4
----   ----   ----   ----
Brod   Pass   xxx    xxx
PSTN   InP    xxx    xxx
LL     InP    xxx    xxx
Fibr   NaN    xxx    xxx
Brod   Pass   xxx    xxx
PSTN   NaN    xxx    xxx
LL     InP    xxx    xxx
Fibr   Pass   xxx    xxx
Brod   NaN    xxx    xxx
PSTN   InP    xxx    xxx
LL     InP    xxx    xxx
Fibr   InP    xxx    xxx
Brod   Pass   xxx    xxx
PSTN   Pass   xxx    xxx
LL     InP    xxx    xxx
Fibr   Pass   xxx    xxx

df['col2'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()))
df_cpt['col2'].unique()

output: 
array(['Passed', nan, 'Pending', 'Registered', 'Applied for sign Off',
       'Verbal', 'Not Applicable'], dtype=object)

df['col2'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().index[0))
```

output:

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Expecting the nan should disappear with the mode of the column. Please help. I cannot paste entire df here as it is very large.

Comment: Please help, I am not able to fix this issue still :(